# submit InfoPath form then send email

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, infopath, 2016

I have an InfoPath form to fill tasks information.
In this form, there is an **assign to** field.

My requirements are submitting the form then send an email to the assigned user with the task details!

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Besides,** the first rule of submitting the date to the `Main connection`, try to add another **`Rule`** to send an email as the following:

- Click on your Submit Button,
- From the above ribbon, properties tab > Add new Rule.
- Select `When this button is clicked` > Submit Data.

[image]

- In the `Rule Details`, Click on `Add` Button.
- In the `Data Connection Wizard` > Select `Submit Data` > Next.
- In `How do you want to submit the data` > select as `an email message`.

[image]

- Then follow the wizard as the shown below:

[image]

> **Note:** at **To** , select your `Assigned To` field from `select a field or group`
>
> **Note**: You can't add body to the email message. meanwhile, you can send the form as an attachment or send only the active form without attachment

- Follow up the wizard, then click  Finish > Publish your form.